# What should I have to do about Access token?

Tags: android, facebook

First, I can log in my facebook and I already save access token in `SharedPreferences`.

However, when I try to this code:

```
JSONObject json_data = null;
try    
{
    JSONObject response = Util.parseJson(new Facebook(Define.APP_ID).request("me/friends"));

    JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
    String name = json_data.getString("name");


}
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FacebookError e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I got an error "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user".

What should I do? I have access token already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it better to use Facebook SDK for Android 3.0 which handles almost everything for you. There is method `executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(Session session, Request.GraphUserListCallback callback`)  from `Request` class which returns list of your friends in callback. Here is getting started guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0 . If you use the sample code from this guide and change the type of request which is executed you will get the same information you're trying to get in code you provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this method and I can retrieve all my friend. But I can retrieve some data from friends such as name, Id, username. How can I get more data from this method?

Answer (score 0):

You shoudn't do any request from `Facebook` Object directly. You have to create `Facebook` Object first and then set the `AccessToken`, Expiry Time and then do the requests as below.

```
FaceBook fb = new FaceBook(APP_ID);

fb.setAccessToken("youraccesstoken");
fb.setAccessExpires(expires);//expires is your milliseconds time.
```

Then you do your requests as `fb.request("me/friends");`

Your are requesting the information without a valid authenticated Session. So you are getting that error. Do authentication and set the access token then you get no problem

Comment: Sorry guy, I still got the same problem. This mean I got wrong access token, don't I?

Comment: @barssala I hope you are not saving accesstoken properly? please check that and also update the code you given in the question with my code otherwise viewers may think the error was you are not setting accesstoken. But I hope with my code it should work because I done it.

Comment: You mean, I have to show you about my `SharedPreferences` when I save my access token. Am i right?